# Visualizing textbox values

Tags: shieldui

I am using Shield UI Chart in order to show data entered by the user in some text fields. Some of them are:

```
var Participants = new Array();
Participants [0]=document.getElementById("ParticipantA").value;
Participants [1]=document.getElementById("ParticipantB").value;
Participants [2]=document.getElementById("ParticipantC").value;
```

and I put the data on the chart using this code:

```
dataSeries: [
            {
                seriesType: 'line',
                collectionAlias: 'chart',
                data: [Participants [0], Participants [1], Participants [2]]
            }
```

I think that I am making it all correct, however there is no data showed at all. I checked that the function is being called, so the problems should be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one error I can see, is that the values of the text fields are not in the correct format. Although you might be entering numerical values, you need to convert them explicitly, in order to be used with your Shield UI Chart:

```
var Participants = new Array();
Participants [0]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("ParticipantA").value);
Participants [1]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("ParticipantB").value);
Participants [2]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("ParticipantC").value);
```